# Contains method for comparing in multiple table

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF code first. Two tables.

Company table (field: CompanyName) and Tag table (TagName). Company table has a link to the Tag Table

```
    public class Company   
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string CompanyName { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to retrieve all companies where CompanyName contains string that is been passed and also retrieve all companies that have that string as a tag

```
        var result = from c in _db.Company
                     select new CompaniesVM  
                     {
                         Id = c.Id,
                         CompanyName = c.CompanyName
                     };

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            result = result.Where(s => s.CompanyName.Contains(searchString));
        }
```

My database contains:

Company name: test1

Company name: company test

if I run the code with searchString "test" it only captures the first record. Contains method does not capture the second record. Why is that? How do I capture all records with "test" string?

Also if I have TagName "test"

Company name: ABC Inc. Tag: TagName : test

How do I look into Tags table as well and get the companies?

I am using Many-to-Many example schema below

[image]

Can I do it all in one query? maybe using lazy loading method?

much appreciated if you can point me to a similar example or sample code

Comment: Is the 2nd company "test" or "Test"?

Comment: all are lower case "test"

Comment: @artm you are right I rechecked it wasnt lower case. Opps. Do you know how to check records in Tag table as well?

Comment: Tag table or Tag column? From your sample it looks like Tag is another column in tha same table, then do `result.Where(s => s.CompanyName.Contains(searchString) || s.TagName.COntains(SearchString))`

Comment: @artm it is a Tag table. The company table has a link to the Tag table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contains is case sensitive so if your data is uppercase and your searchTerm is lower case, they won't match. If you want to ignore case when searching use `result.Where(s => s.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()))`. To search the Tag table as well as Company table join them

```
from c in _db.Company
join t in _db.Tag on c.field equals t.field
select new { Companyname = c.CompanyName, TagName = t.TagName}
where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && (c.CompanyName.Contains(search) || t.TagName.COntains(search)
```

Update for many to many, since you have the collection on Company:

```
from c in _db.Company
select new {
     CompanyName = c.CompanyName
}
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) 
      && (c.CompanyName.Contains(search) || c.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName.Contains(search))
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please see it, I didnt think I have to mention it is many-to-many so I cant directly do join. Do I need to create 2 separate queries? Or somehow I can do all in one? using lazy loading? thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks Artm works! Can you please explain me c.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName.Contains(search) works? Why you included Any() why it wouldnt just work with Contains() method?

Comment: Have a look at Any definition, Any will check all Tags inside c for the Contains condition and return true if any of the Tags contains the search keyword. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: About case sensitive: the query runs in the database, so it depends on the database collation whether or not the query is case sensitive. Usually, database columns are not case sensitive.